# Running mulithreading in python flask over some files give ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: multithreading, flask, flask-restful

i am trying to execute a python script while responding to an api request but script take a bit time to execute so I am trying to return the response ann run the script simultaneously using multithreading. But i gives me this error.** ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.**
here is my request code

```
def post(self,var1=None,var2=None):
        args=self.createDoc_args.parse_args()
        doc_file=args['doc']
        doc_filetype=doc_file.filename.split('.')[1]
        doc_filename=doc_file.filename.split('.')[0]
        csv_file=args['csv']
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, header=None)
        csv_filetype=csv_file.filename.split('.')[1]
        if csv_filetype!='csv':
            MySqlDatabase.close_connection(self.cursor, self.db)
            abort(http_status_code=406, message="Please Upload .csv File")

        
        status_id=1
        # Get the current time
        current_time = dt.datetime.now()

    # Add 5 minutes to the current time
        new_time = current_time + dt.timedelta(minutes=5)
        query="INSERT INTO doc (title, doc, csv, date_created,status_id,eta) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
        val=(doc_filename+'.'+doc_filetype,doc_file.read(),csv_file.read(),dt.datetime.today(),status_id,new_time) 
        self.cursor.execute(query,val)
        doc_id=self.cursor.lastrowid
        #Commit changes and close connection
        self.db.commit()
        q = queue.Queue()
        q.put((doc_file, df))
        MySqlDatabase.close_connection(self.cursor, self.db)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=custom_code, args=(q, ))
        thread.start() 
        return jsonify(message='Your blog is being generated')
```

this code runs the script

```
def custom_code(queue):
    doc_file, df = queue.get()
    # This is the code you want to run after a specific request
  
    print(df,"junaid")
    response=write_Article(doc_file,df)
    print(response)
```

I think thre problem is with the files in the arguments as the main function returns response. all the files in main functions get closed  which throws the error.